# Get running status of python program in PHP

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Hi I am doing a project with Raspberry Pi. I make a python program which have an endless loop inside. I also make a PHP website which call to that python program, make it run in background by this way:

```
$call = "sudo python ../python/readver12.py > /dev/null 2>&1 &";
shell_exec($call);
```

Everything seem okay, but I don't know how to get the status of my python program is running in background or not, and make it available in my website with PHP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is many ways to do that:

**Try get the logs from terminal**
You can throw some logs at your terminal while running your endless python script, and capture it with PHP

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html

**Write on files and read with it with php**

Straight forward, you write in file with python and read with PHP
http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

**API REST On PHP website and python with cURL**
You can use cURL inside your python script to comunicate with your endpoints in php and get the needed data.

cURL: http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/index.html

PHP Api Rest: https://www.codeofaninja.com/2017/02/create-simple-rest-api-in-php.html

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your advice, base on that I made a log file from python script, and compare last time modified with current time by the way using filemtime in PHP  to capture the status.  It worked :D

Answer (score 0):

With shell_exec() PHP will wait to continue your script until the application you're calling exits and will return the output of that application as a string. When your application picks back up the child is already done (or you've hit the [PHP time limit](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)).

It sounds like you want to start the process and monitor it while it's running. For that look at [proc_open()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) and [proc_get_status()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-get-status.php).

Comment: Thank for your advice, I will try to do this tonight